# Beginner Recursion in ANTLR, no call stack?

Tags: recursion, antlr, antlrworks

Is there recursion in ANTLR in the sense that there is a call stack?  Example:

```
parenset
:   LPAREN
    parenset*
    RPAREN
;

LPAREN: '(';
RPAREN: ')';
```

Should just verify that there are as many left parenthesis as there right.  However in ANTLRWorks 1.4.3, in the interpreter when I type in '((()))', I get

[image]

Where are my other right parens?!  Am I doing something incorrect?  Thanks!

Comment: If there is no 'call stack' then how would I go about insuring that there are as many left parens as there are right?

Comment: can you give the entire `.g` file

Comment: grammar Test;


options
{language = 'CSharp2';
output=AST;
}

Comment: Thats all thats missing is the grammar name and the options

Comment: You can omit the `*` character at `parenset*`.

Comment: @Sonson, no, you can't just remove the *: that would cause the grammar to keep trying to match an `(`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use ANTLRWorks' interpreter: it is notoriously buggy.

If I use the debugger in ANTLRWorks (not the same as the interpreter!) with the grammar:

```
grammar T;

parenset
  :  LPAREN parenset* RPAREN
  ;

LPAREN : '(';
RPAREN : ')';
```

and provide the input `((()))` I get the following parse-tree:

[image]

So, to answer your question:

> Where are my other right parens?! Am I doing something incorrect?

No, you're not doing anything wrong: ANTLRWorks' interpreter is messing things up for you. Whenever your grammar contains predicates or recursive rule-invocations, better use the debugger or write your own test class.

Comment: If `(()())` is allowed, the `*` cannot be replaced by `?`. But I guess `()()` should be allowed, too. Then `parenset : LPAREN parenset? RPAREN parenset?;` should be right. (Untested.)